# Question about regular languages

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, regular-language

Let $L$ be a regular language over the alphabet $A=\{0\}$. Is it true that the language of binary representations of $n$, such that $0^n\in L$ is regular?

Comment: Ah, you mean, given a regular language $L$ on $\{0\}$, is the corresponding language over $\{0,1\}$ also regular?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews L can be any regular language over the alphabet {0}. Let's us make a sequence of all the lengths of strings in L and make a new language by representing that sequence as binary strings, is the new language regular?

Comment: Yes, because there is a theorem that says that such a language is either finite or else contains all the multiples of some (finite) set of numbers, minus a finite number of exceptions.

Comment: @MJD what theorem? Can you provide a link, please?

Comment: It's not clear why the *binary* representations of any arithmetic progression is regular. @MJD The problem is the OPs question is a bit vague that the new language is meant to be on two characters, $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews why is it an arithmetic progression? What about (00+000)*, is that an arithmetic progression?

Comment: @paulpaul1076: From some point on, yes: it gives you every $0^n$ for $n\ge 2$. You’ll find the theorem in question [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/175/26206).

Comment: @paulpaul1076 All regular languages on a single letter represent an arithmetic progression, plus a finite set of elements. Finite sets are easy to add or remove from regular languages.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews by "+" I mean "or".

Comment: @paulpaul1076 Ah, then Brian's right - that language is all lengths greater than $1$ and the empty string, which is an arithmetic progression, plus the finite set containing the empty string.

Comment: [“What are the possible sets of word lengths in a regular language?”](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/164/what-are-the-possible-sets-of-word-lengths-in-a-regular-language) discusses my claim that all such sets are eventually periodic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes.  Let $v(u)$ be the binary value of a binary word $u$. By definition,
$$L = \{u \in \{0,1\}^* \mid 0^{v(u)} \in R\},$$ where $R$ is some regular language.
First of all, since $R$ is regular, $S = R \cap 0^*$ is also regular and 
$$
L = \{u \in \{0,1\}^* \mid 0^{v(u)} \in S\}.
$$ A regular language on the alphabet $\{0\}$ is semilinear, that is, a finite union of languages of the form $\{0^r\}$ some $r \geqslant 0$ or $0^r(0^n)^*$ for some $r, n$ such that $0 \leqslant r < n$. Since regular languages are closed under finite union and since the languages of the form $\{0^r\}$ are clearly regular, the problem boils down to the following question:

> Are the languages $L_{r,n} = \{u \in \{0,1\}^* \mid v(u) \equiv r \pmod n\}\ $ regular?

In fact, $L_{r,n}$ is accepted by the following DFA: 
$$\mathcal{A} = (\{0, \ldots, n-1\}, \cdot, 0, \{r\})$$ where the transitions are given by the rules
$$
q\cdot 0 = 2q \pmod n \quad\text{and}\quad  q\cdot 1 = 2q + 1 \pmod n.
$$
The reason is that, for any binary word $u$, $v(u0) = 2v(u)$ and $v(u1) = 2v(u) + 1$.

Comment: Can you please explain why you wrote $S=R\cap 0^*$ isn't $S$ the same as $R$? And what does $2q$ in the transition function mean? Also, I don't understand what you mean in the last line.

Comment: Never mind the last line, I got it now.

Comment: The $2q$ I also understand, but not the intersection thing..

Comment: I misread your question and thought that $R$ was a language over $\{0, 1\}$. Of course, it makes no sense to introduce $S$ if $R$ is a language over $\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks. What is $L_{k,r}$ did you mean to put n there instead of r?

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the notation.

Comment: Nice answer! Is there an easy way (or a good reference) to see that every regular language over a 1-letter alphabet is semi-linear?